# Get multiple value in table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am beginner in PHP. I have one table `No, Date, FileName, FileSize, Attachment Code, FileLink, Share`.  I just click share button there will be a box below this. Give it a mail id and I just click share button. So, my Problem is click on any of the share button passing same id .. My code is here:

```
<form>
    <?php
         include "connect.php" ;

    $attchquery= mysql_query("select * from eduploads order by id desc limit 5") ;


    echo "<table style='width:100%' class='table'>" ;
echo "<tr>" ;
echo "<th>No</th><th>Date</th><th>File Name</th><th>FileSize</th><th>Attachemnt Code</th><th>File Link</th><th>Share</th>" ;
echo "</tr>" ;

$count = 0 ;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($attchquery)) {
$count++ ;
echo "<tr>" ;
echo "<td>",$count,"</td><td>",$row['filedate'],"</td><td>",
$row['filename'].".".$row['fileext'],"</td><td>",
$row['filesize'],"</td><td>",$row['fileid'],"</td><td>",
"<a href='".$valueres['settingsvalue'],$row['filelink']."'>Download</a></td><td>",
"<input type='hidden' value='".$row['fileaddname']."' name='emailvaluepass'><input type='submit' value='Share' name='singlemailshare' class='btn btn-primary'></td>" ;


echo "</tr>" ;


}


echo "</table>" ;



    ?>



<input type='text' name='singleemail' required>
</form>


// get value

if(isset($_POST['singlemailshare']))
{
echo $single_email_sharing = $_POST['singleemail'] ;
echo $single_email_id = $_POST['emailvaluepass'] ;  // Only get last value

}
```

How to fix my problem? Can you give me good examples?

Comment: each row would have to have it's own `<form>` wrapped around it.

Comment: easier would be `<a href="whateverscript.php?emailvaluepass=$whateverYouWannaPass">Share</a>` styled as a button.

Comment: _sidenote:_ do not use mysql_* functions anymore, as they are old, unsecure, deprecated and __removed__ in "latest" php version. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @Jeff  how do you think.. Please Explain..